# How to get socket information previously passed to a bind() call?

Tags: sockets, windows-xp, port, bind, winsock2

Winsock 2, windows xp sp3.

I have a socket, it was previously passed to the bind() function, now I want to get this information from the socket.
More specifically, I want the port number that the socket was bound to.
All I have is the SOCKET instance.

How would I go about doing this?
The socket is UDP by the way.

My purpose is that I want to create a new raw UDP socket and build the ip header and udp header and tunnel information through the raw socket instead, but I don't know what to put into the source port because I don't know what it was bound to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getsockname()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should help you.